# Prononciation non claire

Tags: prononciation, argot, jargon

Au point « [1899s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tRIDpltfojo&list=RDCMUCGCPm2edWmhUmiyy9Tk7D8A&index=17&t=1899s) » de ce movie on peut entendre « *Là ça se confirme, ce truc a donc pété  <quelque chose incompréhensible pour des oreilles normales>* ».

Est-ce que quelqu'un aurait une certitude quant à ce qui est dit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

J'entends «Là ça se confirme, ce truc adore péter des bagnoles».